# IPN is not fired when customer closes paypal site

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

My website has a option for customer to pay by paypal.
After fill the order, customer will be redirected to paypal site. If customer paid, an IPN event will be fired to my server and I will know this customer is paid. But if this customer close the paypal site without payment, I have no IPN event so I don't know this customer paid or not.

How can I handle this problem?

Comment: No IPN = do nothing. I don't understand what you are asking?

Comment: If no IPN is fired so which time I can set my order status to canceled or unpaid? I think there is some option or API that I can check?

Comment: The order shouldn't even be in the system then no?

Answer (score 0):

You could set up some logic in your system to write the order id to your database, and then have a script run every so often to check to see if you received an IPN for that order.  If no IPN has been received, you can delete the order from your system, or log it for investigation.